# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when rendering Flask template

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've been attempting to link my rendering template to my code, as it attempts to render the index.html. I have been encountering a:> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I think it has to do with the loop to render the output from my MongoDB query. I've checked the logic in isolation and it functions, but I'm clearly missing something in relation to the template.
I've included the template, the code and the trace.

A pointer as to what I'm missing would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**TEMPLATE** - Index.html

```
{% block header %}
<h1>{% block title %}Contacts{% endblock %}</h1>
  <a class="action" href="{{ url_for('contact.create') }}">New</a>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% for contact in contacts %}
  <article class="contact">
    <header>
      <div>
        <h1>{{ contact['fullName'] }}</h1>
      </div>
        <a class="action" href="{{ url_for('contact.update', id=contact['_id']) }}">Edit</a>
    </header>
    <p class="body">
        <div>
        <p>{{ contact['firstName'] }}</p>
        <p>{{ contact['lastName'] }}</p>
        <p>{{ contact['dateOfBirth'] }}</p>
        <p>{{ contact['generation'] }}</p>
        <p>{{ contact['region'] }}</p>
        <p>{{ contact['dateOfBirth'] }}</p>
        <p>{{ contact['interests'] }}</p>
        <p>{{ contact['relationships'] }}</p>
        </div>
    </p>
  </article>
  {% if not loop.last %}
    <hr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**CODE**

```
from . import contact
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
)
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort

from .db_mongo.database import Database

ct = Blueprint('contact',__name__)

@ct.route('/')
def index():
    
    db = Database.initialize()
    contacts = Database.dbName.find('Contacts')
    render_template('contact/index.html',contacts=contacts)

 
@ct.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
# @login_required
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstName = request.form['firstName']
        lastName = request.form['lastName']
        birthCalDay = request.form['birthCalDay']
        birthCalMth = request.form['birthCalMth']
        birthCalYr = request.form['birthCalYr']
        region = request.form('region')
        error = None

        if not firstName:
            error = 'First name is required.'
        
        if not lastName:
            error = 'Last name is required.'

        if not birthCalDay:
            error = 'Calendar day of birth is required.'

        if not birthCalMth:
            error = 'Month of birth is required.'

        if not region:
            error = 'Region of contact is required.'

        if error is not None:
            flash(error)
        else:
            contact.__init__(firstName,lastName,birthCalDay,birthCalMth,birthCalYr,region)
            contact.createContact()
            return redirect(url_for('contact.index'))

    return render_template('blog/create.html', regionNames = [{'name':'Europe'},{'name':'Africa'},{'name':'Asia'},{'name':'North America'},{'name':'Central America'},{'name':'South America'},{'name':'Middle East'},{'name':'Oceania'}])
```

TRACE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Kenneth\Documents\Projects\BirthdayAssist\app\contact.py", line 16, in index
    render_template('contact/index.html',contacts=contacts)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Kenneth\Documents\Projects\BirthdayAssist\app\templates\contact\index.html", line 7, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}
  File "C:\Users\Kenneth\Documents\Projects\BirthdayAssist\app\templates\contact\index.html", line 8, in block "content"
    {% for contact in contacts %}
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\runtime.py", line 403, in __init__
    self._iterator = self._to_iterator(iterable)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\runtime.py", line 411, in _to_iterator
    return iter(iterable)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Check the value of `contacts` before passing to to the template.

Comment: It may be because `.find()` method of your Database call doesn't return an iterable object. You have to make sure, by looking at the docs that what you get back from that is actually an iterable object. Or you can make a nasty trick using jinja2, that is, you can surround your for loop with this conditional `{% if contacts|length > 1 %} your code {% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be the use of the way I was using the find method for MongoDB. I had set my method to require a filter parameter passed however, I didn't need any specific filter for this query.